Number Link Hidden Word
I am developing a paper based escape room idea and this is one of the puzzles but I need a sense of the difficulty of the puzzle and the clarity of the instructions.
The three texts on the left side are just flavour and can be ignored.
The instructions:
Link each number with its partner connecting only orthagonal squares. Once you have done so, every square of the tableau must have been used once and only once. The final link will start to provide the key.
Hint Texts:
Hint 1: sfbe uif jotusvdujpot jo uif mjolt
Hint 2: jhopsf uif mfuufst bu gjstu
Hint 3: spurz zahya dpao jvsvby

I am wanting people to solve the puzzle.  Thank you for the suggestions

For the solution, this puzzle can be solved quite systematically:
First, let's color in the ends so that we can connect them easier (I'll bold the originals so we can remember where to read from):

Now, let's look at the bottom right:

 In order for the green 1s to be connected, O and A must be along that path (or it gets trapped in the corner.) Similarly, S and N must be along path 2, so the S above must be on path 1. This forces the U above the ending 8 to go on path 8.


 

Now, let's look at the top left corner:

 Let's take a look at the K near the top left corner. Assuming the path has to be "walkable" in one trip, this K cannot be on path 8, as it would get stuck. It's also impossible for it to be on path 3, since connecting the 3s through K would box in path 8. So it must be on path 7, as are N, I, L, and H. This forces the D and R to path 8, which in turn forces the C, A, and E to 7 We can fill in the H on path 8 to get this:


 

Now, let's look at 7:

 Path 7 clearly has to wrap around the top before coming back to complete itself, or it would block off path 4. So we can wrap path 7 around the entire top row and down the right most column until L:


 

There are some more spaces we can fill in now:

 The S below the ending 3 is the only way path 3 can be formed. Once this is done, no other path can occupy the A space there without a dead end, so it completes path 3.


 

The easiest way to continue from here is to

 assume that path 1 continues by W and not T and prove that this is impossible. This is relatively easy to do, since the U on path 8 will now leave a dead end wherever it continues. So path 1 continues with T, and path 8 with S, E, T. This means we can continue path 7 with A, Y, and finish 4. From here, continuing 7 with H would block 8, so we finish 7 with V:


 

Now let's look at the S in the bottom left corner.

 If it was on path 5, it can be reached by either E or H, the unused one forms a dead end. If it was on path 6, it can continue with either L or H- the unused one forms a dead end. So the key insight to finishing this off is that this S is on path 2. Connecting the 2 and S in any way but the L forms a dead end, so we can connect it and continue path 2 through the left side:


 

And from here, the solution is trivial:

 

So let's take a step back and see what the links are:

 1. TSOA  2. LSEHTTOECXEREWSN  3. AS  4. EU  5. LAOUTTH  6. LREPSOT  7. VYALUEINEACHLINK  8. DRIHTEHTESU

Okay, this doesn't look promising, but if we start at 8:

 Reading 8 backwards gives us "Use the third". From here, we can mash the results up (flipping some as needed, and noting the extra letters) in order to get USE THE THIRD V(Y)ALUE IN EACH LINK TO SPE(R)LL (A)OUT THE(U) A(S)NSWER EXCE(O, should this be a P?)T THE(S) LA(O)ST. In English, this is USE THE THIRD VALUE IN EACH LINK TO SPELL OUT THE ANSWER EXCEPT THE LAST. Taking the third letter from each (counting the number, except in #1, where it doesn't count?) gives us the answer, OSSUARY!


Awesome and you are right about the "P"
